# Debezium's JdbcSinkConnector does not create tables from kafka connect topics

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have task to implement audit log with debezium in PostgreSQL. Here is what I googled and researched:

1. I need to deploy 3 services (kafka broker, kafka connect and zookepeer).
2. I need to create 2 config for connectors. One for catch сhanges in DB and send them to kafka connect and one for consume messages from broker kafka and send them to another PostgreSQL database.

And here is what I have at the current moment:

1. docker-compose.yaml for services and PostgreSQL database.
2. Two json configs for connectors

`docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: quay.io/debezium/zookeeper
    ports:
     - 2181:2181
  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    image: quay.io/debezium/kafka
    ports:
     - 9092:9092
    links:
     - zookeeper
    environment:
     - ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
     - 5432:5432
    environment:
     - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    command:
      - "postgres"
      - "-c"
      - "wal_level=logical"
  connect:
    container_name: connect
    image: quay.io/debezium/connect
    ports:
     - 8083:8083
    links:
     - kafka
     - postgres
    environment:
     - BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092
     - GROUP_ID=1
     - CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=configs
     - OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=offsets
     - STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=statuses
```

PostgreSQL Source connector:

```
{
    "name": "source-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.hostname": "postgres",
        "database.port": "5432",
        "database.user": "postgres",
        "database.password": "postgres",
        "database.dbname" : "postgres",
        "topic.prefix": "stargazer",
        "schema.include.list": "public"
    }
}
```

JdbcSinkConnector

```
{
    "name": "stargazer-sink-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics.regex": "stargazer.public.*",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/sink",
        "connection.username": "postgres",
        "connection.password": "postgres",
        "insert.mode": "insert",
        "table.name.format": "${topic}",
        "primary.key.mode": "none",
        "schema.evolution" : "basic"
    }
}
```

Here is what I got:

1. Kafka connect is creating topics. After creating it tracks changes when someone edited data. And send data to topics.
2. I got error on trying to consume messages and creating tables in destination database.

I get thse errors:

> org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to process a sink record

> java.sql.SQLException: Cannot ALTER table 'name' because field 'Id' is not optional but has no default value

I tried use "JDBC Sink Connector for Confluent Platform", but I got almost same errors and kafka connect could not create any tables.

My expectations, for example, standard use-case:

1. User changes some data.
2. Debezium catch this changes and send them (JSON format, like [this](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/tutorial.html))
3. Sink connector, on other side kafka broker, consume message from topics and save it in PostgreSQL
   3.1. Before consuming, sink connector create tables according on topic list

I read docs about [JDBC connector](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/jdbc.html) and about [PostgreSQL](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/postgresql.html), but I really do not understand why those errors are happening and I will be grateful for any advice.

Thank you!